# cannot find symbol addActionListener()

Tags: javafx

I am a beginner in javafx.I have a function button_loop() that is supposed to dynamically generate a specified number of buttons and add an action listener for each button as it is generated.The buttons are then stored in an ArrayList and the ArrayList is then added to a HBox. The buttons are generating fine. However, when I attempt to add an action listener like so:

```
button.addActionListener(this)
```

And despite implementing the actionListener interface,I get the following error:

```
        error: cannot find symbol
       button.addActionListener(this);
     symbol:   method addActionListener(dummy_td)
     location: variable button of type Button
```

The code for the function is:

```
void button_loop() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(connection, user_name, password);
    PreparedStatement st = c.prepareStatement("select service_name from services");
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) { 
        String service = rs.getString("service_name"); 
        Button button = new Button(service);
       button.addActionListener(this);
             buttonlist.add(i,button); 
    }
     hboxx.getChildren().addAll(buttonlist);
}
```

I've been trying to figure this out for 2 days..please help.

Comment: Probably you are importing the `Button` from `java.awt`. Check the imports again, and make sure you are importing the javafx Button. Awt/Swing buttons has `addActionListener` method and javafx Button has `setOnAction`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's either

```
button.setOnAction(this);
```

(allows only for a single event handler added this way)
or

```
button.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, this);
//              event type    ^^^^^^     |  ^^^ handler
```

**Note:** if you get this error it may be worth checking [the JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html), if the member even exists.

Comment: Also googling `javafx button handler` yields this as the first result: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/button.htm

Comment: I tried the first option. It required typecasting:  button.setOnAction((EventHandler<ActionEvent>) this); but now I'm getting an exception : Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: buttonloop cannot be cast to javafx.event.EventHandler. (buttonloop is the class name)

Comment: @VidhyaSen Then clearly your class doesn't implement `EventHandler<ActionEvent>`.

Comment: I didn't implement EventHandler<ActionEvent> and I was also using addActionListener() for a javafx Button. Now my code is working fine.